# HTTP message via browser

Tags: http

Is it possible to send a HTTP message to client via browser by typing

> http://CLIENT_IP:PORT/MESSAGE
>
> http://192.168.1.1:7777/HELLO

If so could you give me some link to such project or example code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is, provided you have a *http server* listening on port `7777` of host `192.168.1.1` that will get your message and do something with it.

Comment: So the server has to receive it first so it can send it to client, correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will get the message as the route or path in the server. The specific variable will vary depending on the language and framework you’re using.